# Jquery resize bottom element based on element above dynamically and smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a situation where I have a fixed outer div and three divs inside, of which the middle one is toggleable. On hiding this div, I want the bottom div to increase in height at the same time so that it takes up the empty space.

When the middle div is show again, I want the bottom div to decrease in height at the same time. However, even though I'm just reversing the hide code, the height of the bottom div doesn't adjust as expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     var bottomHeight = $('#outer').height() - $('#top').height();
      $('#bottom').css({'height': bottomHeight + 'px'});
    });
    
    // Hide toggle
    $('.button a').click(function() {
     var bottomHeight = $('#bottom').height(),
        toggleHeight = $('#toggle').height(),
          togglePadding = parseInt($('#top').css('padding-bottom')) * 2,
          newHeight = bottomHeight + toggleHeight + togglePadding;
      $('.hide').slideUp();
      $('.show').slideDown();
     $('#toggle').slideUp(400);
      $('#bottom').animate({
          height: newHeight + 'px'
        }, {duration: 400, queue: false});
    });
    
    // Show toggle
    $('.button a').click(function() {
     var bottomHeight = $('#bottom').height(),
        toggleHeight = $('#toggle').height(),
          togglePadding = parseInt($('#top').css('padding-bottom')) * 2,
          newHeight = bottomHeight - (toggleHeight + togglePadding);
      $('.show').slideUp();
      $('.hide').slideDown();
      $('#toggle').slideDown(400);
      $('#bottom').animate({
          height: newHeight + 'px'
        }, {duration: 400, queue: false});
    });
```

```css
#outer {
      width: 200px;
      height: 500px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
#toggle {
      padding: 20px 0;
    }
    
#bottom {
      border: 1px solid red;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button show" style="display: none">
      <a href="">Show</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button hide">
      <a href="">Hide</a>
    </div>
    <div id='outer'>
      <div id="top">
        <div id="fixed">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus facere itaque similique, nulla quos quae, et suscipit est quia vitae aperiam magni ex error accusantium obcaecati repellat excepturi dolor facilis.
        </div>
        <div id="toggle">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, eos laboriosam eveniet consequatur dolores, eaque molestias cupiditate quidem quasi mollitia. Vero sequi eos quia nostrum perspiciatis temporibus maxime ex? Numquam.  
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="bottom">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati quis dolorum ad molestias facere rerum expedita minus natus voluptatum debitis cumque dolore sint ea saepe neque necessitatibus est, optio dolorem.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi, fuga, soluta sint blanditiis optio similique, explicabo deleniti debitis veniam doloremque fugit qui voluptatem nulla magnam quos perspiciatis recusandae provident corrupti.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jr95eg8f/3/)

Comment: wrap the complete jquery code in document.ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your codes a bit, this is what i did:

```
$('.button a').click(function() {
  if ($("#toggle").is(":visible")) {
    $("#bottom").animate({
      height: $("#bottom").height() + midHeight
    });
    $(this).text("Show");
  } else {
    $("#bottom").animate({
      height: $("#bottom").height() - midHeight
    });
    $(this).text("Hide");
  }
  $("#toggle").toggle("height");
});
```

I used just one button to do the job.

[Here is the JSFiddle **demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/t5n1sneg/)

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I made the code use a single button to toggle, instead of two. Also, your buttons were `<a>` tags with an empty `href` attribute. It was closing the document and everything was getting blank. To create a `href` that doesn't send you anywhere, do it like this:

```
<a href="#">Some link</a>
<!-- ----^ -->
```

This snippet will save the `#toggle` div's inner height in the attribute `data-height`. It will later be used to adjust the `#bottom` div's height.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bottomHeight = $('#outer').height() - $('#top').height();
  $('#bottom').css({
    'height': bottomHeight + 'px'
  });
});

$('#toggleBtn').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("toggled");

  var $toggle = $("#toggle"),
    $bottom = $("#bottom");

  var bottomHeight = $bottom.height();
  var toggleHeight = $toggle.innerHeight();
  var toggleHeightAttr = $toggle.attr("data-height");

  if ($(this).hasClass("toggled")) {
    $toggle.attr("data-height", toggleHeight);
    $toggle.slideUp(400);
    $bottom.animate({
      height: (bottomHeight + toggleHeight) + "px"
    }, {
      duration: 400
    });
  } else {
    $toggle.slideDown(400);
    $bottom.animate({
      height: (bottomHeight - toggleHeightAttr) + "px"
    }, {
      duration: 400
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

#toggle, #bottom {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="toggleBtn" type="button" value="Toggle!">
<div id='outer'>
  <div id="top">
    <div id="fixed">
      Fixed lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
    <div id="toggle">
      Toggle lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    Bottom lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati quis dolorum ad molestias facere rerum expedita minus.
  </div>
</div>
```

You were also binding both the show *and* hide events to the same handler:

```
$('.button a').click(...);
```

When you click the button, it was trying to both show and hide `#toggle` at the same time.